# Using Paypal Login API

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, paypal

I've been trying to get the Paypal Login API to work.

[Login With Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button/)

Problem one is that the [Paypal Javascript Button Builder](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/) is not working... no code is produced.

Problem two is that when I generate the appropriate code using the Paypal PHP core sdk, it pops up a screen that does nothing.
Code sample below:

```
<?php
$sdklib="sdk-core-php-master/lib";
require_once("$sdklib/PPConfigManager.php");
require_once("$sdklib/PPConstants.php");
require_once("$sdklib/common/PPApiContext.php");
require_once("$sdklib/auth/openid/PPOpenIdSession.php");

$apicontext = new PPApiContext(array('mode' => 'sandbox'));
$clientId = "AaggjRACLgNPQNEF83qQchE8_KzyKS4mCxmeaTDHTPSFp4hsGlAx4KPMqfZP";
$scope = array('openid', 'email'); 
$redirectUri = 'http://uc.mithril.com.au/testloginreturn.php';
$openidurl = PPOpenIdSession::getAuthorizationUrl($redirectUri, $scope , $clientId,  $apicontext); 

echo "<a href=\"$openidurl\">Login Here</a>";
?>
```

Clicking on the revealed link again produces a blank screen.
Is there some obvious step I am missing, or is the Sandbox just not working right now?

Comment: Shortly after posting this the button builder started working, lending credence to the "sandbox not working right now" theory.

Comment: I finally broke down and create a whole new app in "my apps", which seemed to get it working. However, it is only allowing "openid" in scope. Anything else is returning "Client Validation Error: Invalid scope."

Comment: I am have same issues. When you created first app, did you have the allow login selected with all the correct requested info requested or change it after? I did it after and guessing that is the problem maybe.  Going to create a new app and see how that works.

Comment: I did not initially have all the login options set, so it could be it. I've seen someone else claiming they had to create a second app before they could get anything to work,so I'm starting to think that there is some bug blocking the first app. See my eventual solution below.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue I

- Created a new application in My Apps on Paypal Developer
- Clicked on 'Advanced Options' in the Login With Paypal feature.
- Made sure all the "Information Requested from Customers" boxes were ticked.
- Made sure the "Privacy Policy" and "User Agreement" URLs went to a valid page.
- Checked "Use Seamless Checkout" and "Allow the customers who haven't yet confirmed their email address with PayPal"
- Hit Save.
- Went back again and re-entered the Privacy Policy URLs a second time because they didn't save the first time.
- Made sure "scope" only contained valid data, as per [Paypal Scopes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/)

NB: The button generator only worked intermittently, and the default scope setting contained invalid options.

Comment: There are indications that the first app created just will not work. After getting the second app working smoothly, went back to the first and checked all the settings. Still nada: login page returns nothing.

Comment: I had the same issue: to fix it double check that the user data declared in "paypal.api.scope" property match the flags checked under "Information requested from customers" section