# PayPal LogIn Button in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, paypal

I am trying to add a "Login with PayPal" button on my PhoneGap app. I am following the instructions on this stackoverflow question:

[Using Paypal Login API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833762/using-paypal-login-api)

I created an app and matched the settings under advanced options. Now I think I am not understanding this correctly. These are the settings I used on the Dynamic Log In with PayPal Button JavaScript Builder (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/):

```
<body>
    <span id="myContainer"></span>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
    login.render ({
        "appid": "MyClientId",
        "authend": "sandbox",
        "scopes": "email address locale",
        "containerid": "myContainer",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "returnurl": "http://localhost"
         });
      });
</script>
</body>
```

Now it does come back to my localhost page but that url contains this:
  http://localhost/?error_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&error_description=Client+Validation+Error%3A+Invalid+scope.&error=invalid_scope

What does this mean? Why is it saying that scope is invalid and client validation error etc. It did come back to the page that I specified. Also, what should have come back from this? I am having trouble understanding what will be the next step after this request. Here is what I understand: In my PhoneGap application, I will have this button showing up for user to make a payment to me. On clicking this button, user should be prompted to select to either pay by logging in with their PayPal account or by entering card number. I did do this in an Android PhoneGap project and that was what was presented. Is the JavaScript function authorizing me as a valid user by inputting all those details? It is the user who should get authorized. Please will appreciate any efforts to help me understand this. I am doing all this in Sandbox testing environment, so I have a generated credit card number for a buyer and business facilitator account. Here is what I saw when I tried doing the same thing on Android PhoneGap project:

[image]

Update
So this is what I did. I changed my call to the following:

```
    <script>
    paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
    login.render ({
        "appid": "Af7N5ZkdMg_bh4Uo6_xvGDOBhlDUTptF3BcAsJsHiCj4MmajQt7XTfXIjDqSWeax7HI-C6iDlnlJbfOn",
        "authend": "sandbox",
        "scopes": "email",
        "containerid": "myContainer",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "returnurl": "http://localhost"
      });
   });
</script>
```

I received this window now:
But I haven't got the OAuth access token like the developer site says that I should have in order to make any requests. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Update: I made further progress by logging in with valid PayPal credentials. After verification, I received the page which was specified under redirect uri. In that url, I had code= "A Very Long Code"  appended. Now how do I get the OAuth code from this code so that I can do next step of asking the user on clicking Pay with PayPal button? I need to make that POST call as mentioned in API through JavaScript. Way I figured would be on click of a button. I just tried putting in a URL with the required clientID, secret, code and redirect url but it gives me an error stating

error_description: "client id or secret is null",
error: "invalid_client"

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locale` is not a valid scope name. Use `profile` instead.

source https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/

Comment: Please check my update to the question. I was able to make some progress but still stuck. Any help will be appreciated.